# How to set grid layout correctly in CSS

Tags: html, css

```
 <div class="template-form__list-wrapper--row">
        <%-- company information --%>
        <div class="template-form__list-item">
            <div class="template-form__item-label template-form__item-label">Company</div>
           
        </div>
        <%-- person in charge --%>
        <div class="template-form__list-item">
            <div class="template-form__item-label template-form__item-label">PersonInCharge</div>
            <input form="formCasePost" name="CasePostFormBean.contractorPersonnelName">
        </div>
        <%-- department --%>
        <div class="template-form__list-item">
            <div class="template-form__item-label">Department</div>
            <input form="formCasePost" name="CasePostFormBean.contractorDepartmentName">
        </div>
        <div class = "case-post__list-company">default</div>
        <div class = "case-post__list-company">Add new comapny</div>
    </div>
```

`CSS`

```
.template-form__list-wrapper--row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 1rem;
}

.template-form__list-item {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 10rem 1fr;
    gap: 0.75rem;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}

.template-form__item-label {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 0.25rem;
    height: 100%;
    width: 10rem;
    padding: 0.25rem 0;
    background-color: var(--main-color--2);
    border: 1px solid var(--border-color--1);
}
.case-post__list-company {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
    width: 5rem;
    color: var(--main-color--1);
    background-color: var(--button-color--1);
    border: 1px solid var(--main-color--1);
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px var(--border-color--3);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Now this content show like follows
[image]

But my desired result is like follows

[image]

Is this correct to edit grid layout in `template-form__list-item` ?
If someone has opinion,will you please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

Too much usage of both flex and grid property. I fix your code a little bit, both markup and styles. (It exactly behaves like your intended styles, hope it helps!)

```css
.template-form__list-wrapper--row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.template-form__list-item {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.flex-wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.input-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.template-form__item-label {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1rem;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0.25rem 0;
  background-color: var(--main-color--2);
  border: 1px solid var(--border-color--1);
}

.case-post__list-company {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="template-form__list-wrapper--row">
  <div class="template-form__list-item">
    <div class="template-form__item-label template-form__item-label">
      Company

      <div class="input-wrapper">
        <input form="formCasePost" name="CasePostFormBean.contractorPersonnelName" />
        <div class="flex-wrap">
          <div class="case-post__list-company">default</div>
          <div class="case-post__list-company">Add new comapny</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="template-form__list-item">
    <div class="template-form__item-label template-form__item-label">
      PersonInCharge
    </div>
    <input form="formCasePost" name="CasePostFormBean.contractorPersonnelName" />
  </div>
  <div class="template-form__list-item">
    <div class="template-form__item-label">Department</div>
    <input form="formCasePost" name="CasePostFormBean.contractorDepartmentName" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for comment, `Company` must be aligned by next input box.
 are there any changes of this code ?  Thanks !

Comment: I edited my code. Removed align-items: center from .template-form__item-label. Now the text "Company" is aligned with input boxes in other texts.